# Store output of C program in shell

Tags: c, shell

I have a C program which gives some output. I am compiling the C program via the shell but I need the output from the `run` C program and store in shell.

Edit.

Save the output to a shell Variable.

Comment: I am sorry, I just wanted to save to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want to store the output of the program in a variable. Unix shells offer a facility that's called **command substitution** to do just that. Depending on your shell, you can do either :

```
output=$(./run)
```

or

```
output=`./run`
```

Bash supports both. If, however, you want to save the output to a file, you will need to redirect the standard output stream to a file. You can do this like this :

```
./run > output.txt
```

Or, if you want to see the output while the program is running and save it to an output file as well, you can use the `tee` utility and pipe the output of your program to it.

```
./run | tee output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your output into a file like this:

```
./run > file
```

If you want to store it into a variable, you have to decide which shell we're talking about. It depends whether you have a windows shell, or linux bash..

Comment: That's called redirection, not piping.