# how to pass on some output from a c++ program to the shell so that it can be used in the shell

Tags: c++, shell

Is there any good way i can make some data created by my c++ program available to the shell after exiting the program?

I have a c++ program, inside which i have a string containing a path:

```
std::string path = "/home/some/path"
```

I want this path to be available after the c++ program exits main and i am returned to the shell, so that i can use that path (e.g. cd to that path).

I have considered/tried the following approaches:

- I tried making an environment variable in c++ program using `setenv()`. However the environment variable only exists while in the c++ program, and it is apparently [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183117/how-to-change-environment-variable-in-shell-executing-a-c-program-from-that-c-pr) to make those changes visible in the shell after exiting the program.
- (considered) writing the path to a temporary file, so that a bash script could later access the details of the path from it. However i have read many suggestions to not do that due to security vulnerabilities.
- I tried calling the bash script from within the c++ program, using `system()`. This does not work if i try to `cd` to that directory (exiting the program will keep me in the same directory as before).

I figure that if i am desperate, i could have my program `cout` the path, and use the solutions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429566/store-output-of-c-program-in-shell):

```
$ ./program | tee output.txt
```

Then the path is stored inside the file. This works technically, but has the undesirable effect of creating a file and printing the path to the screen, and is basically creating a temporary file.

another option to, again, cout in my program, and use command substitution. running in the shell

```
$ var=$(./program)
```

storing the path in var. This didnt work because my program does many things including requiring user input before calling

`std::cout<< path << std::endl;`.

Particularly, i have observed this approach to not display a curses window, which is required for the program.
the only solution that has worked is piping the output to tee.

Comment: yes that is what i meant thanks! edited.

Comment: "shell" is not a programming language or a program, see its tag's description. You may want to tag it with the actual shell you are using.

Comment: You *can* execute things using `system()`. Why and how that failed for you is unclear. Also, your question looks like a so-called "xy problem", so you may be asking the wrong question altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are only an input, they cannot be used to return any information from a program.

You are already using `std::cin` and `std::cout` for user input, and `std::cerr` should be reserved for error messages. However, you can have the shell open more filedescriptors, and have your program write to those. However, [doing this with pure C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor) is not possible. But if you don't mind using POSIX C functions:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fdopen(3, "w");
    fprintf(f, "some path\n");
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
./program 3> output.txt
```

This of course creates an undesirable file. I don't think there is any way to store the output from an extra filedescriptor directly to a variable in bash. However, you could create a temporary file inside `/dev/shm`, so it will never be written to disk, or create a FIFO object and redirect the output from the program to the FIFO, and then read it back. For some examples of how to do this, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261194/bash-redirect-output-to-a-variable-or-file-descriptor-then-read-from-the-vari).

Comment: Thanks. if i write to /dev/shm do i need to manually remove the file afterwards? because it using RAM do i need to check if the file is not too large? if so, i would appreciate some further guidance on how to do so properly, thanks again

Comment: Yes, you'd have to remove it. The easiest way is to use the trap command to [clean up before bash exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129923/how-to-run-a-command-before-a-bash-script-exits).

Answer (score 0):

You could write the output that you want the user to see to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Only output what you need your shell script to see to `stdout`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::clog << "Enter data: "; // clog prints to stderr like cerr
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

Then this will work:

```
var=$(./program)
```